Can the UK government do anything about a foreign media platform rooting for civil war in the UK?
FT reports:

British officials have faced resistance from X over calls to take down posts that are deemed a threat to national security, as Elon Musk launched a series of jibes on the site about the UK and Sir Keir Starmer.
Though several companies such as Google, Meta and TikTok have been quick to respond by scrutinising and removing flagged posts, X has been less responsive and has kept concerning content up, according to people briefed on its activities.
The billionaire and self-declared “free speech absolutist” has launched a series of incendiary attacks on Starmer’s government over its handling of far-right protests over the past week, stating over the weekend that “civil war is inevitable” following the riots across the country.

Can the UK government do anything other than retort to Musk (which they did), i.e. put any blocks on a foreign platform that roots for civil war in the UK?

N.B. thowards the end of that piece, FT mentions the Online Safety Act 2023, which might allow Ofcom to fine foreign media companies wtih a UK presence. Howerver it says that the Act "will not be fully enforced until next year". OTOH the Wikipedia's summary of Act itself says that it envisages to "preserve access to, journalistic or "democratically important" content such as user comments on political parties and issues." So, I guess it might be subject to some interpretation in cases like this.

The UK might have been in a stronger position as part of the EU as the EU has not been averse to prodding the big digital companies and has the market size clout to make it stick.  Oh well.  On the other hand:  is "rooting for civil war in the UK" fully representative of Musk's current round of ranting?

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: probably given that he did publicly dig Tommy Robinson's tweets (according to those articles). There are books likewise digging him with titles like "Tommy Robinson and The Coming Civil War" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tommy-Robinson-Coming-Civil-War-ebook/dp/B07PNP231H

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica And (in case you didn't know): "Tommy Robinson, founder of the far-right English Defence League, was among the first to call for nationwide protests, urging his 800,000 X followers to “hit the streets.”  He recently fled Britain, where he was facing contempt of court proceedings." https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/london-high-alert-far-right-demonstrations-come-capital-rcna165567 FWTW, he claims he's just on holiday in Cyprus https://www.lbc.co.uk/news/i-havent-fled-the-uk-tommy-robinson-hits-out-at-comments-he-is-on-the-run-after/

Technically he still has time return voluntarily https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uUh38KYKhk

Here a former Twitter executive also references the Online Safety Act as a potential remedy.

The basic principle would be, if your company wants to have customers/ make money in some country, then it has to do so according to the laws of this country. That applies to companies on the internet just as well as to anyone else.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: https://youtu.be/nKRSetGI_Wk?t=1346

The UK has blocked Russian and Jihadist websites, often in conjunction with sanctions and proscription of organizations under terror legislation, but blocking Twitter would be politically unacceptable because too many journalists and politicians use Twitter. (And a lot of other politicians and public figures have made remarks in favor of civil war both in the UK and US - usually hedged by "if so-and-so happens there will be civil war" - so you might not want to block everyone who does it.)

If this belongs here and not Law SE, please edit to explain why.

@BrianZ: the gov't in the UK can usually pass new laws, assuming they have the typical majority behind them and not experiencing an MP 'rebellion'. Whether the latter is likely to be the case for some such ['anti-X'] measures is mostly a political Q. Some interesting notes here https://history.blog.gov.uk/2014/09/12/chaos-and-censorship/ of how press censorship worked in the UK during the war, by the way.

@BrianZ: and likewise a discussion whether some possibly extraterritorial measures are likely to be effective, i.e. whether some kind of sanctions could work, is also unsuitable to Law SE. I see there was even a call for Musk to be sanctioned https://www.theguardian.com/technology/article/2024/aug/12/elon-musk-should-face-arrest-if-he-incited-uk-rioters-says-ex-twitter-chief

@timetakesitstoll My suggestion was for you to edit your question. These clarifications are too important to bury in the comments. Otherwise the intent of the question isn't clear.

They could do four things:

Block Twitter/Musk from making money in the UK, or at least make it much harder for them to do so. Ban Tesla cars, ban payments for advertising to X, ban Starlink, etc. The UK controls 3.5% of world GDP so this can sting companies a bit.
Force UK internet providers to block access to Twitter. Parliament is supreme in the UK and there's no First Amendment equivalent, so they could restrict access to speech in any way they wish. Of course VPNs and such still exist so some fraction of Britons will still be able to use Twitter. They already block many websites for copyright reasons, so the technical capacity is already in place.
Issue an arrest warrant against Musk and/or Twitter executives. The US is unlikely to agree to enforce such a warrant but it would cause some headache for the company.
Huff and puff in public but do nothing in practice. This is the default outcome. At the end of the day politicians care more about retaining power than they do about some vague calls for 'civil war'. Bashing Musk is quite popular among many circles so they could keep doing it for years/decades to come without taking any meaningful action. For a very recent example see how Iran is threatening Israel that they're going to retaliate "any day now" for nearly a month :-)


Technically, a VPN can easily block access to Twitter for UK-based users. And technically, the UK government could make it costly for any VPN with paying UK-based customers not to do that.

@gnasher729 Let me tell you about bespoke VPNs set up on $5/mo VPCs...

@gnasher729 they’d have to ban all crypto in the UK for starters because dozens of VPNs accept it for payment and would happily tell the UK government to go pound sand. Plus there’s TOR and other free proxy solutions. Internet censorship is pretty hard, you need something like the Chinese Great Firewall to do it effectively.

@JonathanReez That argument is for people who are hellbent on reading Twitter. Normal people would see a message “access to Twitter from the UK has been blocked because..,” and stay away. Same applies to Alamar. 100% censorship is hard. 90% effective isnt. And the 90% hurts Twitters bank account.

OTOH interfering with Tesla would likely not be legal. Independent companies.

@gnasher729 it would not be legal in the U.S. constitution (it would be a bill of attainder) but the UK has no constitution so they could do whatever they want to any company.

@gnasher729 As for “90% is okay”, I’ve recently read that Russian opposition channels on YouTube haven’t seen a decrease in traffic after YouTube was banned in Russia. The most politically engaged people will keep on reading it.

Going after Musk personally and his other companies, would depend on whether he is personally charged with anything and what his roles in those companies are... But if he plans to do business somewhere he has to play by those rules. Though not sure he's residing in the UK, more like Ireland which would be EU law and they already investigate his noncompliance and have issued fines https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/germany-fine-twitter-hate-speech/ the $30 billion dollar fine is false, but something is nonetheless happening.

2/ The UK doesn't have 1 constitutional document because that shit evolved differently, but they nonetheless have afaik a number of documents that take similar effect... And much like most westerns states they also have some level of protection of free speech or conversely restrictions on censorship https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_in_the_United_Kingdom The U.S. is only special in regards to being notoriously racist and company friendly while the rest of the world values individual civil liberties higher.

3/ That depends on the shit he's doing. Like atm the complaints are largely about violating local business regulations, that's not going to result in arrest warrants and extradition attempts, but rather fines unless he idk moves to Germany and tries some Nazi stuff then local laws would apply to local residents (duh). Though often enough U.S. corps do tax evasion by moving an HQ to a tax haven, meaning there can be subsidiaries of twitter to whom those laws directly apply.

4/ The other thing in which that could hurt their pockets is that if they don't comply with the laws or don't pay the fines, countries can simply blacklist them as a company. That won't do much directly, but if no local companies are allowed to advertise on twitter, they make no money. Like having users alone isn't going to make you money and if they all use VPNs and shit to protect their privacy then milking them for their data isn't going to be as easy either. So yeah running that as a non-profit or net-negative is expensive.

5/ Are you sure that is just politicians? Could think that having racist mobs destroy your city based on bullshit information, would also get regular citizens worried about that and put some pressure on politicians to do something about it.

"you need something like the Chinese Great Firewall to do it effectively." - and even then, it's just more annoying to work around rather than impossible. I've always managed to find a functioning VPN whenever I've travelled in China.

Couldn't MI6 put polonium in his coffee and make it look like somebody else did it? Or do some really nasty, damaging, but non-attributable stuff? Screw his finances? Because that's what I'd be thinking about.

@JonathanReez Minor point - the UK does have a constitution, but it is not in a single document but in 400 years of case law. And the most important constitutional rule is probably that Parliament is supreme. This means you are right to say that Parliament could do anything to any company - it's just that the reason is the supremacy rule rather than the lack of any constitutional law.

They could try arresting top executives at these social media sites. For example, France has just arrested Pavel Durov, one of the founders of Telegram, a messaging platform, for enabling illegal activity on the platform including  crimes related to illicit transactions, child sexual abuse, fraud and the refusal to communicate information to authorities.

This is a complex topic that nobody can give you a full answer to in a Stack Exchange answer.
The Internet is a new enough medium that how to apply national laws to it (an inherently international medium) isn't yet an entirely settled question. National politicians and executive agencies (whether in the UK, the US, Germany, Malaysia, China, or Australia) certainly would all like their laws to apply to all websites because, after all, those websites can be accessed in their countries and could have an impact on public opinion there... yet whether that is a good thing for democracy, freedom of speech, and the Internet as a worldwide communication medium (at least ideally), and to what extent it is practically enforceable, is certainly debatable.
(Quick reminder that the Arab Spring happened to some extent because Arab countries didn't, or weren't able to, really enforce their laws on Western social media.)
Starting points for further research:

How can Russia enforce the Wikimedia fines?
How exactly could a TikTok ban be enforced?
Hey Elon: Let Me Help You Speed Run The Content Moderation Learning Curve (contains examples of ways that national governments have attempted to enforce their laws on the Internet)
LICRA v. Yahoo! (shows how far back this problem goes)
Declaration of the Independence of Cyberspace (early Internet pioneers' dreams that, if you follow the other links here, evidently did not come true)


Don't treat him as being significant
Musk wants influence, and hates being ignored. So ignore him, and stop using X-Twitter. Quite a few Labour MPs have done just that.
Of course, he may sue to try to force people to use Twitter (pace his recent lawsuit against an advertising trade association). But if he wants to act the fool, nobody can stop him.
